# Exists getlocale() method in php?

Tags: php, localization, internationalization

I did not find a `getlocale()` function in PHP...
Is there some way to get the current locale?

```
<?php
$locale="en_US";
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale);
...
...
...
$locale=getlocale(LC_MESSAGES); //I need to get the setted locale!
?>
```

I can not store it in a global variable because I need the CURRENT locale set for LC_MESSAGES, a custom script could change it during code execution.

**Mind, I need "en_US" as getlocale() answer...**

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$locale=setlocale(LC_ALL, 0);
```

and you'll get a string like

```
"LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=C;LC_COLLATE=C;LC_MONETARY=C;LC_MESSAGES=C;LC_PAPER=C;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=C;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
```

The `C` means "use whatever locale is hardcoded" for the system (and since most *NIX programs are written in C, it's called C), and equates to the initial string entry of `LC_CTYPE`

Comment: Ok, but how to get "en_US" string? I setted "en_US" string I would like to get "en_US" string.

Comment: Take the `$locale` string, replace `;` with `&` and then use [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php); then you can get the `LC_CTYPE` entry from the resultant array

Comment: I did not get it, I set "us" and I get "English_United States." maybe this is because I'm using Windows S.O.?